# I call a function bit error notify that a function not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

TypeError: DialogflowHandle.handleMessage is not a function

```
DialogflowHandle.handleMessage(message.body) // here notify handle not a funtion.
```

And here is class:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
class DialogflowHandle {

  handleMessage (sentence) {
    this.request.queryInput.text.text = sentence
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        this.sessionClient.detectIntent(this.request)
          .then(resolve)
          .catch(reject);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2):

`handleMessage` is a method available on **instances** of `DialogflowHandle`. It isn't available as a method of the `DialogflowHandle` *constructor function*.

```
const dfh = new DialogflowHandle();
dfh.handleMessage(message.body);
```

Comment: if I use : const dfh = new DialogflowHandle();
dfh.handleMessage(message.body)

Error is :TypeError: DialogflowHandle is not a constructor

Comment: @NguyễnNhiPhát — I can't reproduce that problem: https://jsbin.com/sidepeyegi/1/edit?js,console It must have something to do with code you haven't shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `static` keyword to your `handleMessage`  method in order you want it to be accessed without creating `DialogflowHandle` object:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
class DialogflowHandle {

  static handleMessage (sentence) {
    this.request.queryInput.text.text = sentence
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        this.sessionClient.detectIntent(this.request)
          .then(resolve)
          .catch(reject);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The function cares about the value of `this` so that doesn't seem like a great solution.